# family photo album,how to optimize its realization?

Tags: export, image-processing, programming, image, files-and-directories

I am Beezy, the eldest daughter of the couple.
I have a lot of photos on paper and I want to make a photo album for my parents, but the task is titanic.
First I use a scanner, to scan the photos that reach and results in a file with 3, 4, or 5 photos, which I will call image01.
then another one that I will call image 02 .
This is where MMA comes in.
It is possible that MMA analyzes the image01 and guided by the blank spaces that are left between the photos by scanning can select those forums cut them and send them to a specific directory.

[image]

[image]

(note they are not always aligned, sometimes they are rotated a few degrees, etc.).

Can you help me, I don't know where to start

Comment: This sounds like a fantastic problem that can be solved in many different ways! Very exciting :) Can you provide a few more details about the constraints of your scans? E.g., are they always at the same size, & so-on?

Comment: Well, the only limitation is the size of the scanner, when you put the photos you arrange them as you can, they can be photos of 10x15 or smaller or larger, there are many varied and can have different orientations, what I put is just an example, now if MMA "knows" when a photo is "upside down" would be great.

Comment: What I imagined is that as there are white parts without scanning maybe MMA could follow those parameters to cut the photo, store it and then save it on the hard disk in a specific folder. I don't know if this process can be done in batches, that is to say 
have a directory with several image01, image02 etc, and when you finish with one you can continue with the next one.

Comment: @CA Trevillian,I guess you have been very busy, would you be so kind as to help me with this problem?